# \textmu doesn't work with newtxtext

Tags: newtx, textcomp

I've read that the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages are preferable to `times`, `txfonts` and `mathptmx`, at least for use with `pdfTeX`.  I'm in the process of writing a paper where some measurements are given in microns (µm).  Unfortunately, the `\textmu` (as well as `\micro` in `siunitx`) is replaced with a Computer Modern replacement.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

This is 10\textmu m.

\end{document}
```

In the compilation process, I see this:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TS1/ntxrx/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TS1/cmr/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textmu' on input line 12.
```

and `LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`

This seems to happen with the `\textohm` command as well (and perhaps others I'm not using).  It looks particularly bad in bold text.  `txfonts` seems to produce output (though the mu symbol isn't quite as nice as it is with `mathptmx`).  Using `mathptmx` causes compilation to fail with `\textohm`. Arg.

I'm wondering if there is some trick that I'm not aware of for getting `\textmu` (or `\micro` from siunitx) to work with these packages.  I'm using version 1.07 of `newtxtext`, dated Dec 25, 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: With `\upmu` you get the symbol you want.

Comment: To use `\upmu`, it seems like I have to enter math mode, which then ignores the text formatting (like bold), which doesn't seem ideal (especially for use with `siunitx`, for example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can correct the wrong behavior with

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\textmu}{\ensuremath{\upmu}}
\renewcommand{\textOhm}{\ensuremath{\upOmega}}
```

However, `newtx{text,math}` don't have companion fonts in the TS1 encoding, so you might receive that warning for other symbols.

For usage with `siunitx`, just change the relevant settings:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-micro=\upmu,text-micro=\ensuremath{\upmu},
         math-ohm=\upOmega,text-ohm=\ensuremath{\upOmega}}
```

With some more work, you can have a version of `\textmu` and `\textohm` that respect also boldface:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textmu}{{\usefont{U}{ntxmia}{\f@series}{it}\symbol{\string"16}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textohm}{{\usefont{U}{ntxmia}{\f@series}{it}\symbol{\string"0A}}}
\makeatother
\sisetup{math-micro=\upmu,text-micro=\textmu,
         math-ohm=\upOmega,text-ohm=\textohm}
```

Italic is not supported, sorry; if you *really* need it, something could be done.

---

## Update 2013-02-15

The last revision (version 1.08) of the `newtx` bundle provides the font definition files for the TS1 encoding in the family `ntxrx`, so the original example works and no workaround is needed any more. From the README file:

> Changes in version 1.08:
>   All corrections affect only the Times mode in text and math.
>    1. Fixed problems with vector glyph in math italic.
>    2. Added missing file `ts1ntxrx.fd`.
>    3. Corrected problems in regular and bold math italic in sizes under 10pt.

Comment: The `siunitx` setup works well, though the renewed commands will ignore bold formatting (for example).  But since I use everything with `siunitx`, it doesn't bother me too much.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tyler Here it is. :)

Comment: Ah, very nice.  Don't worry about the italics, I don't need them at all. :)  Thanks a lot!