# package "charter" and "siunitx" problem with \textohm

Tags: texlive, siunitx, textcomp

Consider the following MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% start code I can't touch
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}                  % Serif: Bitstream Charter
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}  % Monospaced: Inconsolata
%%% stop code I can't touch

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
The offset is $V_{io}=\pm$\SI{1}{\micro\volt} for $R_G$ around \SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}.
\end{document}
```

This will not compile (stock Ubuntu 14.04, TeXLive 2013), with the error:

```
! Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textohm not provided by
(textcomp)                font family bch in TS1 encoding.
(textcomp)                Default family used instead.
```

Now, if I comment out `\usepackage{charter}` it works, and if I comment out the `inconsolata` package will compile, although the greek `mu` in the unit comes out wrong.

Unfortunately, I can't change either package...

Looking around, I found that using (I can't find the Q&A again, sorry) that

```
\usepackage[valuemode=math,unitmode=math]{siunitx}
```

Makes thing compile, but again, the "µV" has a math mu...

(By the way, this gives a  deprecation warning; but changing `valuemode` to `value-mode` as told in the manual gives a "option not found" error...)

How can I fix this, considering the "fixed" part that I can't touch (comes from a local template)?

Comment: I get no error in texlive 2015. In texlive 2013 you can convert the error to a warning with `\usepackage[warn]{textcomp}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, obviously I found what I think is a workaround as soon as I posted it. Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97614/38080) and adapting the symbols names (this is puzzling to me... it's a typo in the answer or really `\upOmega` changed to `\Upomega` and `\textOhm` to `\textohm`?) I can add:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\textmu}{\ensuremath{\upmu}}
\renewcommand{\textohm}{\ensuremath{\Upomega}}
```

...and all seems to work (till now). But still I think there should be a cleaner way.