# Redefine default font weights of certain font and keep compatibility to siunitx

Tags: fonts, siunitx, sans-serif

The font **Open Sans** offers various font weights like, *Light, Condensed Light, Regular, Semibold, Bold* and *Extrabold*.

"Regular" and "Bold" are naturally the defaults for `\mdseries` and `bfseries`, but I'd prefer "Light" and "Semibold" to be the defaults.

**How can I redefine the default font weights in a way, that also [siunitx](/questions/tagged/siunitx) understands them and can `detect-all`?**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{detect-all}

Regular numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}\par
\textit{Regular italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}\par
\textbf{Bold numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}\par
\textbf{\textit{Bold italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}}\par

\medskip
But I actually want:
\smallskip

\sisetup{detect-none}

{\fontfamily{fos}\fontseries{l}\fontshape{n}\selectfont%
Regular numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}\par
\fontfamily{fos}\fontseries{l}\fontshape{it}\selectfont%
Regular italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}\par
\fontfamily{fos}\fontseries{sb}\fontshape{n}\selectfont%
Bold numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}\par
\fontfamily{fos}\fontseries{sb}\fontshape{it}\selectfont%
Bold italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}\par
}

\medskip
But \emph{detect-all} of siunitx fails and I'd like to use the commands above.

\end{document}
```

I thought about creating an new font composed from the sub fonts of Open Sans I'd like to use:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{fosn}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosn}{m}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/l/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosn}{b}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosn}{m}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/l/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosn}{b}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/it}{}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fosn}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{fosn}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand{\mddefault}{m}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\mddefault}
```

Which already seems to work quite good, but the greek letters still fail. Any hints?

[image]

I'm explicitly looking for a non-fontspec solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out how I can do what I want - important is to keep the order "LGR, T1" while using fontenc. Thanks also to egreg, for [his answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97611/textmu-doesnt-work-with-newtxtext/97614#97614).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{fosn}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosn}{m}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/l/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosn}{b}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosn}{m}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/l/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fosn}{b}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/it}{}

\DeclareFontFamily{LGR}{fosgreek}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{fosgreek}{m}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/l/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{fosgreek}{b}{n}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{fosgreek}{m}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/l/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{fosgreek}{b}{it}{<-> ssub * fos/sb/it}{}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fosn}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{fosn}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand{\mddefault}{m}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\mddefault}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{osgreek}{LGR}{fos}{l}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{osgreek}{bold}{LGR}{fos}{sb}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upmu}{\mathord}{osgreek}{`m}

\DeclareSymbolFont{osgreekit}{LGR}{fos}{l}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{osgreekit}{bold}{LGR}{fos}{sb}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{osgreekit}{`m}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textmu}{{\usefont{LGR}{fosgreek}{\f@series}{\f@shape}\symbol{\string"6D}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textohm}{{\usefont{LGR}{fosgreek}{\f@series}{\f@shape}\symbol{\string"5F}}}
\makeatother
\sisetup{math-micro=\upmu,text-micro=\textmu,
         math-ohm=\upOmega,text-ohm=\textohm}

\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{detect-all}

Regular numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}\par
\textit{Regular italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}\par
\textbf{Bold numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}\par
\textbf{\textit{Bold italic numbers and unit: \SI{42}{\micro\meter}}}\par

\[
\int \sum X_\mathrm{\mu\upmu}\mu\upmu\mathrm{\mu\upmu}A + 2 = \SI{42}{\micro\meter\ampere\gram}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]